# Get Children as string with xmlreader and C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xmlreader

I am parsing an xml string using xmlreader in c#, but as i parse i need sometimes to get the full content of a node including children with tags and still be able to continue parsing.

ReadInnerXML and ReadOutterXML break up everything for me

example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<main>
    <parse1> //finding this will get full inner or outter xml - either one - my issue
         <parse2 /> // even getting the children above might still need parse chldren
         <negligeable /> // not all children interest me
   </parse1>
   <parse3>some text</parse3> // not all children of main are the same but all need be parsed
</main>
```

Hope this gives you a general idea of what i need

i can parse 2 and 3 right now and ignore what i don't need but if i use ReadInnerXML or ReadOutterXML when i find  the  tag then it won't let me parse anything else - not even the  tag wich is outside .

ReadInnerXML and ReadOutterXML do return the text i need correctly but cause everything else to not be parsed

**EDIT:** as per dasblinkenlight sugestion, some code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XmlString)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "parse1":
                         Console.WriteLine("Contents of Parse 1: {0}", ?function here?);
                         break;
                    case "parse2":
                         Console.WriteLine("Parse 2 tag exists");
                         break;
                    case "parse3":
                         Console.WriteLine("Contents of Parse 3: {0}", Reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                         break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Result should be (given the test xml)

```
Contents of Parse 1: <parse2 /><negligeable />
Parse 2 tag exists
Contents of Parse 3: some text
```

Am also trying ReadSubTree

Any hints?

Comment: It is very hard to figure out what is the problem without seeing your code. Could you add some of your C# to your question to illustrate the problem?

Comment: ok but the problem is not with code but what i am asking about - basicly iterate twice the same node - i will add code sample shortly

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `ReadSubtree` is not going to help, as it positions the original reader at the end of the element on which it is invoked.  All it really does is provide a "sealed" reader which sees only that element.  But I should add, I don't really understand what you're trying to do.  Please clarify your question if possible.

Comment: yes i noticed that - but i still tryed it - basicly i need to get the contents of either innerxml or outterxml of node parse1 and then traverse it's children, but if i use ReadInnerXml or ReadOutterXml i loose traversability and if i traverse first i loose the position and can't use ReadInnerXml or ReadOutterXml

Comment: Re-edited my code sample and edited expected result to ilustrate better what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically readinnerxml is reading all the way to the end and XmlReader is forward only.
You might get away with XmlDocument, or another way, would be to create another reader from the same Xml content, read to where you are in the orginal, get your string and bin the 'copy'

Comment: i will look into xmldocument tomorrow (almost end of day here). Your second sugestion is basicly what i have been trying to achieve today but i would i know where in the original i am? remember my example is a simple one and i could have n <parser1> tags to parse.

Comment: Just reading my own words got an idea - a counter of tags - then just skip n tags on the copy - will try that tomorrow unless by then someone comes up with a better solution here

Comment: "Basically readinnerxml is reading all the way to the end" - That's what i am seeing - although it only returns up to </parse1>

Comment: Another way is to use the Node to build an Xpath Expression, if some are collections, then XPath's Position() function will do the job. NB XmlDocument loads the entire document, so if it's huge there's a cost.

Comment: The idea you gave me (see my second comment) worked - thamks a million

Answer (score 1):

Using `XmlDocument` you can easily loop through your xml elements and print the things you want

Eg:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(XmlString);

string parse1_Content = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parse1")[0].InnerXml;
Console.WriteLine("Contents of Parse 1: " + parse1_Content);

if(xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parse2") > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Parse 2 exists");

string parse3_Content = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parse1")[0].InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(parse3_Content);
```

Comment: I had tryed such approach becore, only it won't work on more complex examples - for example if there are 2 parse1 elements and only one has a parse2 element it will always print parse 2 exists and i won't know in wich parse 1 element it will reside

Comment: .GetElementByTagName returns you a list of elements, you can check the element parent name before print if 'Parse2' exists, or check if 'Parse1' has child nodes named 'Parse2'. 
Also I recommend you to see the documentation, i think there a lot of methods that can be helpful for you

Comment: i will look into it just in case - but as i stated in Tony answer, i got this issue solved through another method - not perfect but works for me in the initial tests - upvoted your comment